# How to add view below textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, textview, autolayout

I need to add a view below a textview that changes it's height dynamically. In other words my view should be shown when textview reach end of text. If I just add constraint for my view = bottom of screen it will overlap my textview.

Its looks like very easy, but i really stuck on this task

Comment: Try this :  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @SharmaVishal Vishal not helped

Comment: Only adding constraint to bottom of screen won't work, you need to add Vertical constraint between TextView and View..

Comment: @iphonic of cource i did it

Comment: Add screenshot of your View showing constraints added.

Comment: @iphonic [screen](http://disk.karelia.pro/cover/e4WdR9P/screen.png?width=1200)

Comment: Remove height from the constraint for the view in the bottom..

Comment: @iphonic how it would help? i need constant height for my view

Comment: @iosnewbie since you have fixed the height it is not resizing with the TextView it is always that if you want to resize with the TextView you have to remove that height, you can always set a minimum height so the view don't resize to 0. something like height>=100

Answer (score 0):

You are already having enough constraint for your view.I feel, You do not need to provide bottom constraint from superview. Your View contains trailing , leading constrains, height and top from the text view. That should be enough. 
In your case You are forcing view to always be fixed at the bottom.
If text view contains large text it will overlap.
So remove bottom constraints and it should work fine if text view is dynamically changing height.